# How can I connect graphviz nodes that are in records using pygraphviz for dot?

Tags: python, graphviz, dot, pygraphviz

This is a problem I stumbled upon when interfacing with dot through pygraphviz.
I am creating records through labels but I am wondering how to connect ports that are in the records rather than record nodes themselves.

In dot it should look something like this:

```
a00 [shape = "record" label="{{RecordThing1}|{<1>A|<2>B|<3>C|<4>D|<5>E|<6>F}}"];
a01 [shape = "record" label="{{RecordThing2}|{<1>A|<2>B|<3>C|<4>D|<5>E|<6>F}}"];
a00:1 -> a01:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution: 
The `headport` and `tailport` attributes of edges can be used.
e.g.

```
agraph.add_node('a00', 'a01', tailport=1, headport=1)
```

Read more at: https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:headport for instance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small error in the code of the solution posted by tortal: add_edge needs to be used (instead of add_node).

Assuming two structures 'a00' and 'a01' with fields 'f0', 'f1' and 'f2', the 'tailport' and 'headport' edge attributes can indeed be used to link different fields

e.g., for linking a00:f1 with a01:f0

```
from pygraphviz import AGraph
g = AGraph()
g.add_node("a00", label="<f0> text | {<f1> text | <f2> text}", shape="record")
g.add_node("a01", label="<f0> text | {<f1> text | <f2> text}", shape="record")
g.add_edge('a00', 'a01', tailport='f1', headport='f0')
```

Comment: This is your first post.
4 years ago my solution worked. Are you sure the API hasn't changed?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - it is still possible, I used the release 1.5 of PyGraphviz (http://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/latest/pygraphviz.pdf), but it seems from the Graphviz documentation that tailport and headport are edge attributes, and not node attributes (https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html)

Comment: I cannot say that you actually answered the question but I upvoted your comment.
You do not elaborate why my solution is incorrect (it works).
You simply paste a solution w/o arguing why your solution is "better".

Now, I agree that it is better, and yes you solved the problem. But for sake of SO you should elaborate.

Comment: Unless I misinterpreted something, the solution you posted does not work with Python 3.7.7 and pygraphviz==1.5 (see below - I cannot tell for your configuration 4 years ago). Your post has been very helpful since it gave the right direction; I just thought it would be helpful to share an update based on my own experience with the community

>>> from pygraphviz import AGraph
>>> g = AGraph()
>>> g.add_node('a00', 'a01', tailport=1, headport=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: add_node() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given